# Network is unreachable on connect

Tags: ios, c, networking

I have a problem with my app on iPhone. In my country all works fine, but when I travel to USA it doesn't work, so I put trace logs. Checking the logs I saw the next situation:

- In first place I connect to a server and all works fine.
- In second place I try to connect other server (one feature of app to do some checks of app and send some info) and always fail with next error: **Network is unreachable**.

To connect to server I use next code:

```
tcpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

tcpAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
tcpAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPAddress);
tcpAddr.sin_port        = htons(TCPPort);

int result = connect(tcpSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&tcpAddr, sizeof(tcpAddr));

if (result < 0)
{
    // Stop
}
```

After see that, a friend localized in my country tested the same and it worked fine. So, I think that the problem is with the net, but it is very strange.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you asking here?  Call your service provider:(

Comment: Because it happens in more countries, not only USA. In some European countries also happens.. But the las country that I test was USA.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create an IPV6 socket connection for this situation:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27150